# Making definition query table not blue in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, definition-query

I am new to ArcGIS Pro.

I figured out a definition query but it's making the attribute table blue and it hurts my eyes.   I would like definition query tables to be un-colored (white), but I want to retain colors for selecting from within tables using the normal selection process.

How do I do this?

Comment: I have never seen the setting of a definition query apply a color to an attribute table. Please describe in detail the steps you perform to do and then see this; perhaps starting by adding a new layer.

Comment: Well, it's not happening today, so I think it was some sort of a temporary glitch.    (Tried to delete the question, but could not).     If this happens to you,  try exiting the program and coming back later.

Answer (score 1):

By definition query, I think you actually mean a **Selection** on the layer.

At this time (ArcGIS Pro 2.5), it does not appear you can modify the table selection color.

For the selected features in the MAP, you can change the default selection color of Cyan to any color by clicking:

- Project
- Options
- Select **Selection** under **Application**
- The first option of *Set the selection color for all open maps*

Comment: They are two different things.    A definition query permanently hides everything not selected and holds it while you select and un-select other things within the definition query.    A layer selection is temporary and lets you turn the selection on and off.

Comment: I understand the difference - What I dont understand is this "blue" color for your definition query.

Comment: Yes,  when I run the definition query, the entire resulting table is highlighted in bright blue.     It causes quite the headache trying to read.

Comment: Can you take a screen shot and add it to your question?